# cloudcontrol.com tcp port in use & procfile multiple commands & push hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, port, cloudcontrol, procfile

i'm trying to get redmine running on cloudcontrol.com. i've got four questions:

1. i need to do more that start a webserver, for example i need to run rake tasks each time i deploy. can i put those in a one liner? i got the following in my Procfile for testing:

web: touch foobar; echo "barbarz"; bundle exec rails s -p $PORT -e production

but i neither see a file foobar nor do i get barbarz in the log files :(

1. When i login to the server and want to start the application it tells me tcp $PORT is already in use:

u24293@depvk7jw2mk-24293:~/www$ fuser $PORT/tcp   # netstat and lsof is not available
24293/tcp:              10    13
u24293@depvk7jw2mk-24293:~/www$ ps axu | grep 13
u24293      13  0.0  0.0  52036  3268 ?        SNs  15:22   0:00 sshd: u24293@pts/0

by sshd??? why would that be?

1. i need to change this default behaviour during push:
   -----> Rails plugin injection
      Injecting rails_log_stdout
      Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets

or run something after it as easyredmine doesnt like plugins in vendor/plugins (or i cahnge the code of easyredmine quickly). how would i do that (not change the code, run an after hook for that like with capistrano or so)?

1. we have our own gitlab on a dedicated server and for bundle i need to pull those gems. how can i get the public key of the user running the app before the first deployment so i can add it to gitlab?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The web command is only executed in the web containers. Using `run bash` connects you to a special ssh container of your app. See https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#secure-shell-ssh

   Generally, you can not put multiple commands in one Procfile line. Wrap them in a `sh -c '<cmd1>; <cmd2>'` call or use a shell script explicitly.
   Keep in mind that this script will be executed in each container being started. This includes the number of containers you deploy your app with and any redeploys that are triggered by the platform during operation (in case of a node failures, addon changes etc.).
2. In the ssh container the $PORT is used by the ssh server you are connected to.
3. If it is a problem of redmine during runtime, you could remove the plugins in the mentioned  startup script. If it's a problem during the gem install currently you can not circumvent this behavior.
4. Dependencies requiring special ssh keys are not supported right now. If your server supports basic auth over https, you can use the `https://<username>:<password>@hostname` syntax

Comment: thank you for your reply. i talked to cc today and they say that ssh IS supported, its just not completely implemented into the user interface yet. so just write the support an email and request a pub key for your app.